# Execute rails server from ruby app on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.9.3

I must execute a Rails Server (Rails version : 2.3.4, Ruby version : 1.8.7) from a Ruby script ( version 1.9.3).
My ruby script is:

```
system(start G:/app/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe G:/app/name_app/script/server)
```

When I started this script, I got this result:

```
Missing the Rails 2.3.4 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.4 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
```

But I installed that gem on ruby interpreter 1.8.7. In fact if I execute this command in prompt:

```
G:/app/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe G:/app/name_app/script/server
```

Rails server starts.
I checked the environment variables (because my script runs on Ruby 193) but nothing, output is the same error.

Have you got any ideas?

Comment: try this `system("G:/app/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe G:/app/name_app/script/server")`

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work, its output is the same error on script prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Is the location of the gems defined?

Something like:

```
Set GEM_PATH=/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/:${GEM_PATH}
```

You'll want to see if you have gems on your home directory or off the root. You can do this by running `gem environment`

(or) do `bundle install` or `gem install rails` will fix your problem.

(or) it would be the rails issue, upgraded to `rails 2.3.8`

Comment: I think we want under windows `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` is `unix`

Comment: Yes, it's defined. It's defined for Ruby1.8.7 in  directory /Ruby187/... and it's defined for Ruby1.9.3 in directory /Ruby193/... thank

Comment: what's the rack version u using? uninstall the rack and install again the latest one and let us know..

Comment: I use rack 1.1(release 1.4) for Ruby 1.9.3. and 1.8.7.